# How can i load a link in android as this browser style?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to load an url but what i have done is this

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL)))
```

And i got this as result

[image]

But what i want to get as result is this

[image]

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Visit the documentation for more information.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i have tried with a webview and it doesn't show it like i want to

Comment: I would like to show it like the first screenshot shows. whit the "X" in the top left

Comment: Just add a custom toolbar and add that X in that